# Forward messages in Thunderbird without displaying original sender

Tags: thunderbird, forwarding

Is there a way to forward a message in Thunderbird 17.0.2 without showing who sent it to me?

Comment: Copy the email's contents into a new email message?

Answer (score 1):

Strip the sender from the message.